# Set range from two different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I need to set a range that contains only two items:Two sheets(let's say sheetA , sheetB) from two different workbooks (let's say WB1, WB2).I've tried to construct the Range but without success:

```
Set R = Worksheet.Range(WB1.SheetA, WB2.SheetB)
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A range can only reference cells on a single worksheets, in a single workbook, so what you are asking for can't be done.  If you explain what you trying to achieve we might be able to offer an alternative

Comment: Hello chris. I want to replicate the following loop: "For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count" but to count two sheets that I will retrieve from two different workbooks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store two ranges from different workbooks and/or worksheets, then you might use an array of Range objects

```
Dim myRanges(1 to 2) As Range

Set myRanges(1) = WB1.SheetA.Range("A1")
Set myRanges(2) = WB2.SheetB.Range("A1")
```